# O que esta de errado na lógica desse codigo que soma faixas de números?

Tags: c, c++, lógica

Meu algoritmo precisa somar todos os valores entre `a` e `b`, por exemplo se eu digitar `a=3 e b=6` o programa precisa falar `3 7 12 18 (3+4= 7/ 7+5=12 / 12+6=18)` só que ele só faz o dois primeiros depois começa errar.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main ()  
{  

int a,b,i,n,x,c;  

  printf("Digite a: ");  
  scanf("%d", &a);  
  printf("Digite b: ");  
  scanf("%d", &b);  

  c=0;  
  for(i=1;i<=b;i++)  
  {  
    c=a;  
    a=c+(a+1);  

    printf("%d\n ",c);  

  }


    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código é um pouco confuso e tenta fazer coisas demais. Basta iniciar o laço com o primeiro dado entrado e terminar no segundo. O termino está correto, mas precisa começar pelo `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Digite a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Digite b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        soma += i;
        printf("%d ", soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vUnw9n). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bezpjupj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Loop.c).

Comment: entendi, bridagao mano

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, soma=0, i;

    printf("Digite a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Digite b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    for(i=0; i<=b; i++)
    {
        if(i >= a)
        {
            soma = soma + i;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", soma);
}
```

Comment: Por mais breve que seja tente incluir um nota no seu código para auxiliar a compreensão.